# Flutter Downgrade Command

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, downgrade

I want to downgrade my flutter from flutter version `3.0.1` to flutter version `2.10.5`.
When i try to run the following command:

```
$ flutter downgrade 2.10.5
```

i got the following message instead:
[Flutter Downgrade Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6xK4.png)

How can i downgrade my flutter version to version that i want?

PS: I'm using OS ubuntu 20.04

Extra reference:
[Extra Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6o35.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can not downgrade to specific version. The downgrade command works only for the version you used just before the upgrade.

Example: If you upgrade from 2.8.1 to 3.0.1, the downgrade command will directly downgrade to 2.8.1

So, a workaround might be to use a [Flutter Version Management](https://pub.dev/packages/fvm) tool. Using this, you can use any flutter version in any of you projects

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is:
Download the version of Flutter you need and put it in the place where Flutter is installed In this directory you have "flutter" folder.

In Ubuntu, it is usually located in this path: /home/username/development/flutter

To develop the software with the desired version, just change the desired folder name to "flutter".

For example :

flutter --> flutter-3.x.x

flutter-2.x.x ---> flutter

The Stable channel contains the most stable Flutter builds:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=linux